# Minimizing Drift in 8thWall Web

Tags: 8thwall-web

I'm trying to develop a web AR experience with 8thwall web. It needs to be synced with the physical world and I need 6DOF for this project. I can place my objects and augment them but the problem is that the drift I experience is too much, For example, if I go 4-5 meters away from my initial location I experience about 2 meters drift. I don't experience this much drift with my ARKit projects and I also tested google's 'view in 3d' in searches on the web on Safari and that also didn't give me this much drift. 
 I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong and how can I minimize drift in my project. I develop on my iPhone XS
PS: I also tested a web AR sample on 8thwall website and I also experienced drift issues with that.
Thanks very much